# Sum over time of 1d, limit to last 7d, counter as a value

Tags: prometheus, grafana

Let's suppose I have metric purchases_total. It's a counter ( which constantly increases ).
I would like to make a table in Grafana which:

- Shows the last 7 days
- Sums over 1d

I try to make this query, but it returns nonsense:

```
sum_over_time(sum(increase(purchases_total{deviceType='ios'}[2m])/2)[7d:1d])
```

P.S 2m it's a scraping interval. Also, I put a "Min step" of 1d into a query configuration ( between the legend input field and resolution input field ) to limit a table view ( in Grafana ).

Any advice will be highly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question isn't 100% clear, but I think you are looking for `sum(increase(purchases_total{deviceType='ios'}[1d])` and then use a 1d step to the query_range API with start/end covering 7 days.

Comment: I am afraid I am getting invalid results..The numbers are ~2-2.5 times bigger than they should.

Comment: Can you tell me what is not exactly clear? I want to display a table ( not a Graph ) with 7 records: 1 row per 1 day. The value ( of each row ) shows the amount of purchases made during this day. At the same time, purchases_total is a counter ( which always increasing ) and the scraping interval is 2m, means that Prometheus pulls data every 2m.

Comment: Hm..after some review, we found a bug in our code. Your answer is correct. Thanks

Comment: Do note that each daily point would correspond to total purchases the previous day. i.e. Total purchases with timestamp of 2nd of Oct 2021 00:00:00 UTC would correspond to total purchases during the previous period, so - 1st of Oct 2021. This can be changed if negative offset is applied: sum(increase(purchases_total{deviceType='ios'}[1d] offset -1d) . And here is how to enable negative offsets support: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/feature_flags/#negative-offset-in-promql

Answer (score 0):

The following PromQL query should return the number of purchases for the previous day:

```
last_over_time(
  increase(purchases_total{deviceType='ios'}[1d])[1d:1d]
)
```

It uses [subquery feature](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/) over [last_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#last_over_time) and [increase](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase) functions. The outer `last_over_time(...[1d:1d])` is needed in order to align calculations to boundaries between days in UTC time zone.

The query returns results shifted by one day in the past. This can be fixed by adding `offset -1d` to the query:

```
last_over_time(
  increase(purchases_total{deviceType='ios'}[1d] offset -1d)[1d:1d]
)
```

Note also that Prometheus may return fractional results from `increase()` over integer counters because of extrapolation. See [this issue](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3746) for details. Additionally, Prometheus ignores the difference between the last sample on the previous day and the first sample on the current day when calculating `increase()`. This may lead to incorrect results for slow-changing counters. See [this comment](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/issues/1215#issuecomment-850305711) and [this article](https://medium.com/@romanhavronenko/victoriametrics-promql-compliance-d4318203f51e) for details. Both issues should be addressed soon by Prometheus developers according to [this design doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1y2Mp041_2v0blnKnZk7keCnJZICeK2YWUQuXH_m4DVc/edit).

In the mean time it is possible to use [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/), which provides `increase()` function without these issues.